# Python: How to calculate Difference btw Current Year and Year from Column?

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, difference

I have a column "DateBecameRep_Year" that contains only year values in it (i.e. 1974, 1999, etc.).  I want to create a new column in my dataframe that calculates the difference between the current year and the year in the "DateBecameRep_Year" field.

Below is the code I tried to use:

```
df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year'])

df_DD['Current Year'] = datetime.now().year
df_DD['Current Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_DD['Current Year'])

df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'] = df_DD['Current Year'] - df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year']  
df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'] = df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')

df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'].head()
```

This is the output I get which looks very strange:

[image]

My hypothesis is that this has something to do with the following:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you extend your question with a small reproducible data set (in text/CSV format) and desired data set? Currently it's now clear what are you trying to achieve... Why would you want to convert year (integer) to `datetime` dtype?

Comment: I guess you just need a difference between years? if so remove the third line from the code.

Comment: Replace all you code with `df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'] = datetime.now().year - df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year']` and that's all, no ?

Comment: yes, you are right... I should have just kept df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year'] as a float and subtracted -- thanks!

Comment: @PineNuts0, i guess you just need: `df_DD['Years_Since_BecameRep'] = pd.datetime.now().year - df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get the different year number, you could simply use substraction, no need to convert to datetime.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year #get current year
df_DD = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"DateBecameRep_Year":[1999,2000,2015,1898,1788,1854]})
df_DD['Current Year'] = datetime.datetime.now().year
df_DD["Years_Since_BecameRep"] = df_DD['Current Year'] - df_DD['DateBecameRep_Year']  # substract to get the year delta
```

`df_DD` will be:

```
    DateBecameRep_Year  Current Year    Years_Since_BecameRep
0   1999                2017            18
1   2000                2017            17
2   2015                2017            2
3   1898                2017            119
4   1788                2017            229
5   1854                2017            163
```